# How to obtain target feature name from a sklearn `Bunch`

Tags: python, scikit-learn

One can obtain the "column headers" from an sklearn `Bunch` as `Bunch.feature_names`.  However, this does not give the "column header" for the target variable.  How does one obtain the "column header" for the target variable?

e.g. for the Iris dataset:

```
>>> data.feature_names 
['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)', 'petal length (cm)', 'petal width(cm)']
```

In this spirit, the "column header" for the target variable would be something like "species" (since `data.target_names` gives `array(['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'], dtype='<U10')`.  Does a sklearn `Bunch` have a means to obtain the "column header" for the target, e.g. "species"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact thing that you want is not possible.  However, you can do the following:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

data = load_iris()
print(data.DESCR)
```

And read the description

`The data set contains 3 classes of 50 instances each, where each class refers to a
type of iris plant.`

Comment: The hope was that a column header existed, as I have an extensive pipeline and simply extracting it and having it flow through the pipeline would be nice.  I suppose the implication in your solution is that the answer to "does a `Bunch` have a means to obtain the 'column header' for the target" is "no"?

Comment: Correct. There is no other <direct> way to do this

Comment: You could load into a DataFrame rather than a Bunch. That will include the Target column. 


irisDF = sns.load_dataset('iris')   ;


print(irisDF.head())